# rewriteRule .htaccess not working properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a RewriteRule in .htacess but it's not working and I don't know why.
This is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^agencia/agencia-marketing-digital-bh$ /agencia/section.php?id=$1 [L]
```

How it should work:
User acess **www.mysite.com/agencia-marketing-digital-bh.php** and it should change to **www.mysite.com/agencia/agencia-marketing-digital-bh.php**

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: With "should change to" you mean the URL visible in the browser should change? You did not implement any rule that should do that. You'd need to implement an external redirection (`R=301`) and you'd need to rewrite from without to with, not vice versa.

Comment: i changed but its not working

Comment: "its not working" has never helped anyone, anywhere at any time to get help with something. You need to be much more specific: what _exactly_ do you want to do? What _exactly_ is happening in your tests, what not? What entries do you get in your http servers error log file?